# Can a non-shell executable `source` a file for the active shell?

Tags: shell, source

When I'm using a shell, it is (AFAIK) impossible for a shell script which contains a `source somefile` line to affect the parent shell (unless the script was itself sourced, of course).

I want to know if a non-shell executable (written in C, for instance) can effectively `source` a file and have everything be available to the shell as if I had typed `source somefile` on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ type source
source is a shell builtin
```

That’s how it’s possible (that made more sense with your original, longer question).

No, you can’t replicate the behaviour of `source` in an external program (short of exploiting input buffering tricks). It’s the same as with `cd`: only the shell can modify its own internal state, so only shell builtins can modify the shell’s internal state.

Comment: Can you comment on the input buffering tricks?

Comment: It’s disabled by default in most modern environments, but see [CVE-2008-2383](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2008-2383) for the general idea: in many terminals, you can change the title to anything you want, then ask the terminal to tell you what its title is, and exit — so the terminal tells the shell what its title is. If you’ve ever `cat`ted a binary by mistake, you might have seen your shell process rubbish commands afterwards, that’s what’s happening there.